# gcloud managed vm starts too many instances

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Worked through the [quickstart for Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/), then deployed the app to production:

```
gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default
```

After deploying, there are ~12 instances in my dashboard. The exact number seems to vary for each deploy attempt.

[image: 12 managed vm instances started]

I killed all of these, deleted them, and deployed again. ~12 more are created. I tried both manual_scaling and automatic_scaling with no improvement.

My app.yaml:

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
api_version: 1
# [END runtime]

# [START resources]
resources:
  cpu: .5
  memory_gb: 1.3
  disk_size_gb: 10
# [END resources]

# [START scaling]
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
#automatic_scaling:
#  min_num_instances: 1
#  max_num_instances: 1
#  cool_down_period_sec: 60
#  cpu_utilization:
#    target_utilization: 0.5
# [END scaling]

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'

# Temporary workaround for a Cloud SDK bug.
# Ensures that node_modules directory and any .log files are not uploaded (the
# other entries are the default values for skip_files). This will skip any Unix
# hidden files (such as the .git directory)
skip_files:
 - ^(.*/)?#.*#$
 - ^(.*/)?.*~$
 - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
 - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
 - ^(.*/)?\..*$
 - ^(.*/)?.*/node_modules/.*$
 - ^(.*/)?.*\.log$
```

For brevity, I pasted the [output of the deploy command, version info, and other non-essentials here](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/b1eeaf740864a2229ccd).

What am I doing wrong here? What do I need to do to start exactly one instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows twelve different versions of your application has been deployed. The numerical part of the instances names `yyyymmddtxxxxxx` will be same for the same version.

On the Developers Console, go to `Compute > App Engine > Versions` , and delete those versions of the application that you don't need anymore.

Comment: Indeed, even though I'm working in `Compute Engine > Managed VM`, there are versions being created under `App Engine > Versions`. Deleting the instances in Managed VMs does not get rid of them (they just get recreated). But deleting them under `Versions` does prevent them from coming back. This begs the question: How does one deploy so that they aren't created in the first place?

Comment: In fact, you're working with `App Engine Managed VMs`, however the instances are visible under `Compute Engine > VM instances` in case you want to switch from `Google-managed` to `user-managed` mode. You can use `--version VERSION` flag with your gcloud command to explicitly define what version you want to deploy or replace.