# Google cloud - Not able to delete VM machines

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I am new to google cloud. Sometime back i managed to deploy my code on cloud.

I just created 2 VM instances. I am facing following problem,

1. Whenever i deploy new build using cloud sdk(gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default), it brings new machine. this is weird.
2. Tried to delete VM instances in the console (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance#delete_an_instance), seems like deleted for few minutes and then it comes back into console again and again.

Can anyone please help as to how to resolve this issue?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not used version flag (`--version VERSION`) with your `gcloud` command, it deploys new version of the application and will consequently spin up new VM instances.

To fix this, take a look at my answer at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972467/gcloud-managed-vm-starts-too-many-instances/32984856#32984856).

Answer (score 1):

The older app versions in App Engine are still running.  You can navigate to App Engine > Versions and delete unused versions.

If you only delete the VM, App Engine will respawn it.